# How do you close any open UIkit nav accordions via JS?

Tags: javascript, uikit, accordion

By default, clicking a UIkit nav accordion submenu row will close any already open submenu as it opens its own. But if you click a non-submenu nav row, it does NOT close already open submenus. The docs (https://getuikit.com/docs/nav#accordion) perform the same way.

I find this behavior inconsistent and undesirable. Ideally there's be be a `UIkit.nav(element).reset();` method to close all open menu items, but none seems to exist.

My guess is that I need to use the built-in `click` event, but I have no idea how to approach this. UIkit JS docs and examples are few and far between, adding to the challenge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround is here ... **https://codepen.io/neokio/pen/OrMNZY** ... which basically involves finding the index via ...

```
var open_index = $('#left-col > div > ul > li.uk-open').index('.uk-parent');
```

... and then UIkit's native toggle method ...

```
UIkit.nav('.uk-nav-default').toggle(open_index, true);
```

Thanks to @zzseba78 on gitter.im for helping me refine the index.